# Distributing custom Windows AMIs on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I am building a Windows AMI from a base Windows AMI with my custom software on it.
If I distribute this image to customers, am I infringing some ToCs? How does it work given that Windows is proprietary?

Comment: Your custom image should retain a markeplace ID, and user's of it will still be charged w/e the windows license fee is.

Comment: @jordanm What do you mean by "retain a marketplace ID"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share your AMI's, and you are not infringing on any ToC's:

> Amazon EC2 enables you to share your AMIs with other AWS accounts. You
> can allow all AWS accounts to launch the AMI (make the AMI public), or
> only allow a few specific accounts to launch the AMI (see Sharing an
> AMI with specific AWS accounts). You are not billed when your AMI is
> launched by other AWS accounts; only the accounts launching the AMI
> are billed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-intro.html

When you share it with your customers, and they launch the AMI, they are billed by AWS and part of that bill is to pay the licensing cost as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You will not violate any TOCs. AWS itself promote custom AMIs which are highly useful for business continuity plan.
For open-source software, they will work at run time, and for licensed software, only a copy of the software will be installed and the end-user will have to apply their license to make it work! Thus it shouldn't be an issue.

Since you're building a Windows AMI, do use Sysprep tool. It is highly useful in removing unique information from the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) Windows instance, including the instance security identifiers (SID), computer name, and drivers. Duplicate SIDs can cause issues with Windows Server Update Services (WSUS), log-in issues, Windows volume key activation, Microsoft Office, and third-party products.